# Get Week number from given date

Tags: android, calendar

I trying to get the week number for the date given in Android. I am trying the following I don't get the results if I enter for janurary?

Can somebody help me fix this?

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
now.set(Calendar.MONTH,00);
now.set(Calendar.DATE, 12);
Log.e("week","Number "+ now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Above results it is blank...I am not getting any log at all.. The same if I enter 01 I get the week number 7.

Let me know!

Comment: "I don't get the results if I enter for january"? Explain the obtain output and the expected output please. What logs `"Number " + now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)`?

Comment: The double zero can be interpreted at octal number I believe... Anyway, your code works fine in my code...

Comment: Mine works fine also. Output is `Number 3`

Comment: I am getting blank. What could be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12);
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.